# Disable Login with Email in Account Kit

Tags: android, ios, authentication, facebook-android-sdk, account-kit

Just wondering if it's possible to disable users from logging in with their email using the new Facebook Account Kit SDK. To be clear, I only want them to be able to login via Facebook or Phone # (but not email). I tried going through the docs, but haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: It may help to include, rather than *just* using tags, references to Android and iOS in the question text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.

Unfortunately Facebook has not specified that in the documentation.

Here's a screenshot from the Facebook developer console to verify that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Account Kit isn't tied to a specific Facebook account, so a user signs up with their phone number or their email account, not their Facebook account.  From the Account Kit overview:

> Using email and phone number authentication doesn't require a Facebook account, and is the ideal alternative to a social login.

You could [only include the phone number login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios/integrating#sms) from Account Kit and then add in a separate social login for Facebook to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which kind of Account Kit login screen, either email or phone, you want your app to display using the `AccountKitConfigurationBuilder` first parameter as shown in the [Account Kit documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android#smslogin).

I'm going to copy the example from the link to explain a little bit how is it done:

```
int APP_REQUEST_CODE = 90; 
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountKitActivity.class);
AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
            LoginType.PHONE,  // or LoginType.EMAIL if you want to use email validation
            AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE); // or .ResponseType.TOKEN
// ... perform additional configuration ...
intent.putExtra(
AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
configurationBuilder.build());
startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
```